# How should I set the overflow-y for a redactor box located inside #document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a redactor box which will stretch until reaching a specific height (16 lines of words) before appearing a scroll bar and stop stretching.

What I want to do is setting a new max-height of my redactor box (new max-height: 12 lines of words) and let the redactor box display a scroll bar after stretching to the new max-height set(new max-height: 12 lines of words).

This is a portion of the code generated by my browser :

```html
<iframe style="width: 100%; height: 104px;" frameborder="0" class="redactor_textCtrl redactor_MessageEditor redactor_BbCodeWysiwygEditor redactor_">
  #document
  <html>
  <head>
    <base href="http://localhost/community/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/community/css.php?style=23&amp;css=editor_contents&amp;d=1420373561">
  </head>
  <body contenteditable="true" dir="LTR" style="overflow-y: hidden; min-height: 99px;">
    <ol>
      <li>
        <br>
        <br>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </body>
  </html>
</iframe>
```

In order to get that thing, I've tried to write this on my *.css file:

```css
.redactor_textCtrl.redactor_MessageEditor.redactor_BbCodeWysiwygEditor.redactor_ {
  max-height: 300px !important;
  overflow-y: scroll !important;
}
```

That gave me a nice result in setting the redactor box max-height to the new one (new max-height: 12 lines of words)

Problem was, the scrollbar stil did not appear until the old max-height be reached (new max-height: 16 lines of words).

I'd been struggling for a while to edit directly from the browser source and found that extra-editing `overflow-y: hidden` of the code below

```html
#document
<html>

<head>
  <base href="http://localhost/community/">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/community/css.php?style=23&amp;css=editor_contents&amp;d=1420373561">
</head>

<body contenteditable="true" dir="LTR" style="overflow-y: hidden; min-height: 99px;">
  <ol>
```

Into `overflow-y: scroll` :

```html
#document
<html>

<head>
  <base href="http://localhost/community/">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/community/css.php?style=23&amp;css=editor_contents&amp;d=1420373561">
</head>

<body contenteditable="true" dir="LTR" style="overflow-y: scroll; min-height: 99px;">
  <ol>
```

Brought me perfectly what I want: the scrollbar appeared exactly when the `max-height`'d reached 300px (12 lines of words)

**Next problem is I can't edit the code inside the #document from my .css file. 
Any help for this , or any turnaround/simpler method for reaching what I want, please ? 
Thanks in anticipation :)**

Comment: Looks like you are confusing code snippet feature with insert code one, please edit your question

Comment: To set style of iframe BODY (if it is your question), then use e.g: `$("iframe.redactor_textCtrl").contents().find("body").css('overflow-y', 'scroll');`

Comment: Thx for answering, but it does not work. maybe the problem is the redactor is parsed as {xen:raw $qrEditor} inside my template. So, the script can't found the ("body"). Any idea for this, please ? thx

Comment: `it does not work` really doesn't help to find an issue. Instead, describe how you have tried it? Are you calling it once iframe is loaded in the DOM? Cannot you provide online link which replicates your issue???

Comment: I'd like to provide you a link, but I'm working offline in my local host, really sorry. I've triied to paste your code as <script></script> inside my corresponding html template, but then I found out that there is no ('body') written inside that template coz it's parsed as  {xen:raw $qrEditor}. I've tried to find the exact location of that variable, but I can't, I wonder if I should find that $qrEditor first, shouldn't I.